# How to make a hierarchal cluster in R between different dataframes?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have 4 different dataframes of for different city's but with the same variables. I want to make a hierarchical cluster between the dataset of the for city's. I have tried this code to make a hierarchical cluster in R:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(df))
hcd <- as.dendrogram(hc)
```

But this code makes a dendrogram of one dataframe. What I want to do is to make a dendrogram between different city's, so I want to cluster the row's between different city's. I have searched a lot at the internet bit I couldn't found anything about it. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I have also tried to combine the dataset, but then it makes also clusters with the same city's. I want to make clusters between different city's

An example of my dataset is as follows:

I have 4 different dataframes of for different city's but with the same variables. I want to make a hierarchical cluster between the dataset of the for city's. I have tried this code to make a hierarchical cluster in R:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(df))
hcd <- as.dendrogram(hc)
```

But this code makes a dendrogram of one dataframe. What I want to do is to make a dendrogram between different city's, so I want to cluster the row's between different city's. I have searched a lot at the internet bit I couldn't found anything about it. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I have also tried to combine the dataset, but then it makes also clusters with the same city's. I want to make clusters between different city's

An example of my dataset is as follows:

```
      colname_city   col_1   col_2
[1,]  Amsterdam      0.2     0.3
[2,]  Rotterdam      0.3     0.5
[3,]  Den Haag       0.4     0.2
[4,]  Utrecht        0.2     0.1
[5,]  Amsterdam      0.1     0.5
[6,]  Rotterdam      0.2     0.5
[7,]  Rotterdam      0.4     0.4
[8,]  Utrecht        0.5     0.3
[9,]  Utrecht        0.5     0.5
[10,] Den Haag       0.6     0.3
```

Comment: When asking a question, you should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can get an idea of what's going on. Why can't you just combine your different data.frames into a single data.frame to do the clustering?

Comment: You need to merge dataframes first and then apply hclust

Comment: I have also combined the dataset. But when I make a cluster of that it clusters also the same city't, but I want to cluster different city's.

Comment: @PankajSharma I have also tried it but I don't want to have clusters between the rows with te same city name. Therefore I want to try to cluster 4 df's ??

Comment: What would be the desired outcome?!?

Answer (score 1):

To cluster each city separately, a subset of the rows containing the data for the given city needs to be selected. The hierarchical clustering is then applied only to the subset. `data` is your example table.

```
city_hc <- function(city){
    temp <- data[which(data$colname_city == city),]
    hcd <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(temp)))
    return(hcd)
}
```

To obtain dendrograms for all cities, we cycle through all levels.

```
hcds <- lapply(levels(data$colname_city), city_hc)
names(hcds) <- levels(data$colname_city)
```

The result contains a list of all dendrograms.

```
str(hcds)
# List of 4
#  $ Amsterdam:  ..--[dendrogram w/ 2 branches and 2 members at h = 0.274, midpoint = 0.5]
#   ..  |--leaf "1" 
#   ..  `--leaf "5" 
#  $ Den Haag :  ..--[dendrogram w/ 2 branches and 2 members at h = 0.274, midpoint = 0.5]
#   ..  |--leaf "3" 
#   ..  `--leaf "10" 
#  $ Rotterdam:  ..--[dendrogram w/ 2 branches and 3 members at h = 0.274, midpoint = 0.75]
#   ..  |--leaf "7" 
#   ..  `--[dendrogram w/ 2 branches and 2 members at h = 0.122, midpoint = 0.5]
#   ..    #  |--leaf "2" 
#   ..    #  `--leaf "6" 
#  $ Utrecht  :  ..--[dendrogram w/ 2 branches and 3 members at h = 0.612, midpoint = 0.75]
#   ..  |--leaf "4" 
#   ..  `--[dendrogram w/ 2 branches and 2 members at h = 0.245, midpoint = 0.5]
#   ..    #  |--leaf "8" 
#   ..    #  `--leaf "9" 

# plot a dendrogram
plot(hcds[[3]])
```

I hope this is what you needed to do.